# Why does google took 0.3 on the dollar i get

Tags: in-app-billing, google-play-console

[image]

hi, I developed a new app and implemented a 1 dollar pay button in it using anjlab library
when I tried to test it and pay from a credit card it shows me as google will take 0.3 from that dollar
shown in photo

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about 3rd party service policy, not about programming.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/112622?hl=en

> For apps and in-app products offered through Google Play, the service
>   fee is equivalent to 30% of the price. You receive 70% of the payment.
>   The remaining 30% goes to the distribution partner and operating fees.

Comment: do you know other service that i can use it as in app purchase with lower cost

Comment: or even a way so it sends the money directly to my bank account @ceejayoz

Comment: @AbedJabi https://play.google.com/about/monetization-ads/payments/ indicates you must use Google Play for in-app purchases. No, you can't avoid this.

Comment: okay, thank you. one more question, please. This amount includes the transfer payment from google to my bank account or no. because I asked my bank and they said it depends on the sender and if the sender did not pay the amount then we take from you. thank you in advances @ceejayoz